# wcf REST response xml format attribute and inner text

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF rest service that will respond with XML.  Now I can get my XML to show up like this:

```
<Add FirstNumber="5" SecondNumbe="4" Result="9">

</Add>
```

but what i want is this:

```
<Add FirstNumber="5" SecondNumbe="4">
9
</Add>
```

Is there a way to have attributes and innertext using DataContracts?

Answer (score 1):

No. DataContracts are always serialised as elements and do not support attributes. If you want to control the XML you need to use ISerializable or XmlSerializer.

For the latter, you can just apply the [XmlTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) to indicate that a member should be communicated via the inner text of an element.

Comment: well right, but is there a way to have attributes and inner text?  I just know how to get the attributes to show up or have inner text, not both

Comment: Please show the source code where you 'get attributes to show up' using Data Contracts.

Comment: @odyth, I am keen to see your method for getting Attributes populated when using DataContracts. Are you able to provide any further information?

Comment: see this SO article for how to get it to show up like my first example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323651/wcf-rest-response-in-xml-format

Comment: Yes that is using XmlSerializer. To do that you are not using DataContracts. DataContracts, very strictly, do not serialise to XML attributes.

Comment: So is your question: "Is there a way to have attributes and innertext using XmlSerializer"?

Comment: yea.  pretty much i want an easy way to turn an object into xml with attributes and inner text.